# Data created by ios user in an ios app cannot be seen publicly (Using parse.com for login/signup and storing user data)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am building an ios application which has multiple user login. I am using parse.com for login and signup. The user logs in and adds data specific to the application (in my case it is apartment finder) and to himself/herself which gets added to a table on the web server (on parse.com).

Every user has it's own data (apartments in this case) which he/she can see in the their work areas.

The problem I am facing is that I want the data which different user added on the web server to be seen publicly without having the right to edit (I want to keep it readonly).

I am using PFuser, PFObject, PFTableView and ACL as a differentiating factor between two or more users.

I am not posting any code for now. But, if someone can make sense of what I want to achieve and need the code for clear understanding I will post the code.

Comment: If your user posts something it's read only to everyone else but them by nature. Or are you saying once they post something they shouldn't have write priveleges?

Comment: They should have write and read both priveleges. I just want to make the different data added by all the users as publicly available (kind of guest). 

Suppose, we have different leasing companies who come up and add various apartments at different locations. Every leasing company will have their own set of data. I need to make all these apartments available to a guest user who will just have read privelege.

Comment: It happens autonomously. The only way other users can edit other users is if you allow it

Comment: Yea, I know. I am just trying to reason out my doubts as it is not happening. I am still not able to go through it. Let's see if I can find solution. Will keep this post updated.